# How to solve this cycle dependency in c# project?

Tags: c#, .net, cyclic-reference

I am modifying a project (1) (windows service). I was given a utility project(2) and I am using this is my project. I dont know why but this (2) has an initialization using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]` I use a custom config reader in my project as I wanted my own XML structure. The utility has no options to initialize using contructors or methods.

I did not want to change this utility much so I just changed this initialization using AppSettings to the config class in (1) (by creating a dependency to (1) from (2)). I know this is not the way to go about it. If I clean my solution it would be mess.

I could think of some ways. But not sure which will be the correct approach?

1. Have another config file
2. Continue with cyclic dependency
3. Pass on parameters and change the utility
4. (there are too many parameters) should I pass all values as string and write logic in utility to convert them back?

### Project 1

```
using utility;

ns pr1;

CustomConfigReader{ }
```

### Project 2

```
using pr1;

ns utility;
UtilityClass{

  //Initialization of a lot variables
  pr1.CustomConfigReader .......

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the custom configuration code in its own DLL & have (1) & (2) both reference it.  Then modify (2) so it uses the custom configuration code.

Comment: Thanks. I did not think of this before. I have a general clarification regarding this. As I changed it to another dll I found another issue when moving and had to move it the Log class to another seperate dll. I this normal to have several projects under one solution in big projects?

Comment: It is in my office and others I've worked at.  Generally, only very simple projects need only one project in the solution.  For example, my WPF application has several DLLs & even a couple of executable program projects, not to mention two installers in the solution.